# org.json.JSONException: Value MySQL of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, android-volley

I'm connecting the external database and Android with php. I confirmed that the data entered on Android is inserted into mysql table. But, hitting errors on the JSONObject. I followed this tutorial. I just turned the local database into an external database here. - https://github.com/GaKaRi/gakari_android/tree/master/Proj_Manager_v3

I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

**RegisterActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText idText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.idText);
    final EditText passwordText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
    final EditText nameText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    final EditText emailText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailText);
    final EditText phoneText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneText);

    Button regbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registerbtn);

    regbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String userID = idText.getText().toString();
            String userPassword = passwordText.getText().toString();
            String userName = nameText.getText().toString();
            String userEmail = emailText.getText().toString();
            String userPhone = phoneText.getText().toString();




            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){


                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");


                        if(success){

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("register success!!")
                                    .setPositiveButton("ok", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();


                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

                        }

                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("register fail!!")
                                    .setNegativeButton("ok", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();

                        }

                    }catch(JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };


            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(userID, userPassword, userEmail, userName, userPhone, responseListener);

            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);

            queue.add(registerRequest);

        }
    });

}
}
```

**RegisterRequest.java**

```
    final static private String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> parameters;


    public RegisterRequest(String userID, String userPassword, String userEmail, String userName, String userPhone, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, URL, listener, null);
        parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("userID", userID);
        parameters.put("userPassword", userPassword);
        parameters.put("userEmail", userEmail);
        parameters.put("userName", userName);
        parameters.put("userPhone", userPhone);

    }


    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        return parameters;
    }
}
```

**register.php**

```
  <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$mysql_hostname = 'mirpasec.ddns.net';
$mysql_username = 'extern_user';
$mysql_password = 'extern_pass';
$mysql_database = 'extern_user';
$mysql_port = '50106';

$con = new mysqli($mysql_hostname, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database, $mysql_port);
if($con){
    echo "MySQL connect success";
}else{
    echo "MySQL connect fail";
}




$userID = $_POST["userID"];
$userPassword = $_POST["userPassword"];
$userEmail = $_POST["userEmail"];
$userName = $_POST["userName"];
$userPhone = $_POST["userPhone"];


$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO USER VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sssss", $userID, $userPassword, $userEmail, $userName, $userPhone);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);


$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
04-30 15:16:40.651 6063-6063/com.example.ijangmin.stock W/System.err:org.json.JSONException: Value MySQL of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
04-30 15:16:40.652 6063-6063/com.example.ijangmin.stock W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
04-30 15:16:40.652 6063-6063/com.example.ijangmin.stock W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:163)
04-30 15:16:40.652 6063-6063/com.example.ijangmin.stock W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
04-30 15:16:40.653 6063-6063/com.example.ijangmin.stock W/System.err:     at com.example.ijangmin.stock.RegisterActivity$1$1.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:58)
04-30 15:16:40.653 6063-6063/com.example.ijangmin.stock W/System.err:     at com.example.ijangmin.stock.RegisterActivity$1$1.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:51)
04-30 15:16:40.653 6063-6063/com.example.ijangmin.stock W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
04-30 15:16:40.654 6063-6063/com.example.ijangmin.stock W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
04-30 15:16:40.654 6063-6063/com.example.ijangmin.stock W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
04-30 15:16:40.654 6063-6063/com.example.ijangmin.stock W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
04-30 15:16:40.655 6063-6063/com.example.ijangmin.stock W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-30 15:16:40.655 6063-6063/com.example.ijangmin.stock W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
04-30 15:16:40.656 6063-6063/com.example.ijangmin.stock W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
04-30 15:16:40.656 6063-6063/com.example.ijangmin.stock W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-30 15:16:40.656 6063-6063/com.example.ijangmin.stock W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
04-30 15:16:40.656 6063-6063/com.example.ijangmin.stock W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Please post your response along with your question, so that we can take a look into what you are trying to parse. Also, you might also consider removing the server side code. Try to provide minimal code so that we can understand the problem clearly.

Comment: I'll refer to it from next time. Fortunately, I solved it myself. It was mysql's column type size problem. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Great to know that you have solved your problem. Welcome to StackOverflow. :)